# Create sectioned table using Three20 sdk

Tags: three20

I am creating a table using Three20 sdk.  I want to create sections in this table.
Is this possible? If yes, how to do it? Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [TTSectionedDataSource](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_sectioned_data_source.php) docs. The example app that you can get from the Three20 website also shows an example implementation of a sectioned data source that you can use as a working example